# How to change gi history to make look like the commits were applied on a copy of the folder in the repo

Tags: git

I branched out to add a new feature to my code. The changes made in the feature_branch are in a folder A_m(A master). Let's called the modified version of A_m in feature_branch as A_fb. Now when I merge my feature_branch to master, I want the git history to look like changes were made on top of folder A_mcopy(copy of A_m) rather than on A_m.

How Can I make this work?

I have tried to copy the folder A_fb to master_branch (but I will loose all the commits that were made in my feature branch)

Finally after merge my master should have both A_m, A_fb folders

Comment: What do you mean by “on top of folder”?

Comment: If you're using git, just make the changes directly in the folder A_m. Don't make a folder per branch.